# custom reduce function implementation - why is this particular list of arguments passed?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, reduce

I found this super helpful [gist](https://gist.github.com/alexhawkins/28aaf610a3e76d8b8264#file-nativejavascript-js-L77).
In reduce function implementation, a long list of arguments has been passed: `undefined, accumulator, this[i], this, i`. I do not understand why. In my understanding that line should be, `accumulator = callback.call(accumulator, this[i])`. But if I remove any of these arguments, the reduce function works incorrectly. Please help me fill gaps in my understanding!

```
 Array.prototype.myReduce = function(callback, initialVal) {
    var accumulator = (initialVal === undefined) ? undefined : initialVal;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        if (accumulator !== undefined)
            accumulator = callback.call(undefined, accumulator, this[i], i, this);
        else
            accumulator = this[i];
    }
    return accumulator;
};

//tests
var numbers3 = [20, 20, 2, 3];
var total = numbers3.myReduce(function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}, 10);
console.log(total); // 55

var flattened = [
    [0, 1],
    [2, 3],
    [4, 5]
].reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a.concat(b);
});
console.log(flattened); //[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument to `call` is the `this` value to use inside the callback. But this implementation is not using any `this` inside the callback, so the first argument must be `undefined`. If you do

```
accumulator = callback.call(accumulator, this[i]).
```

then you're calling the `callback` with a single argument, the `this[i]` (where `this` inside the callback will be `accumulator`, which definitely isn't what you want).

That said, the implementation in the gist is **incorrect** - it does not call the callback when the last callback returned `undefined`. It also does not properly check the initial value (which may have been passed as an argument, but is `undefined`):

```js
// Unaltered function below:
Array.prototype.myReduce = function(callback, initialVal) {
    var accumulator = (initialVal === undefined) ? undefined : initialVal;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        if (accumulator !== undefined)
            accumulator = callback.call(undefined, accumulator, this[i], i, this);
        else
            accumulator = this[i];
    }
    return accumulator;
};

// My test:
[1, 2, 3].reduce((a, b, i) => {
  console.log('native reduce iteration!');
  return i === 0 ? b : undefined;
}, 0);

[1, 2, 3].myReduce((a, b, i) => {
  console.log('CUSTOM reduce iteration!');
  return i === 0 ? b : undefined;
}, 0);
```

To fix it, call the callback unconditionally (and remember to throw an error if called on an empty array with no initial value):

```js
// Unaltered function below:
Array.prototype.myReduce = function(...args) {
    const [callback, initialVal] = args;
    let i;
    let accumulator;
    if (args.length >= 2) {
        accumulator = initialVal;
        i = 0;
    } else if (this.length === 0) {
        throw new TypeError('Reduce called on an empty array with no initial value');
    } else {
        accumulator = this[0];
        i = 1;
    }
    for (; i < this.length; i++) {
        accumulator = callback.call(undefined, accumulator, this[i], i, this);
    }
    return accumulator;
};

// My test:
[1, 2, 3].reduce((a, b, i) => {
  console.log('native reduce iteration!');
  return i === 0 ? b : undefined;
}, 0);

[1, 2, 3].myReduce((a, b, i) => {
  console.log('CUSTOM reduce iteration!');
  return i === 0 ? b : undefined;
}, 0);

console.log(
  [2, 3, 4].myReduce((a, b) => a + b)
);
```

Comment: understood! what about the other parameters? How are they being used?

Comment: They're not being used in the tests, but `reduce` does accept callbacks that use them - just like other iteration methods, the other arguments are the current index, and the whole object being iterated over, `.reduce((accumulator, valBeingIteratedOver, index, wholeObjectBeingIteratedOver) => {`